# How to close all running activities from another one?

Tags: java, android

I've got some activities which I execute one after another without closing (1->2->3->4). I want to close 1,2,3 activities from 4 and execute a new one; the code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserpickActivity.this, CommunicationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);              
        startActivity(intent);
```

UserpickActivity - 4th activity, CommunicationActivity - the next activity. But after this code all previous activities still worked. How can I close all running activities and execute some new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

When you want to launch `CommunicationActivity` from Activity4, do this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class); // Your root activity
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // Will remove all other activities from the task
intent.putExtra("foo", true); // This is to tell Activity1 to launch Activity4
startActivity(intent);
```

In `Activity1.onCreate()` do the following:

```
super.onCreate();
if (getIntent().hasExtra("foo")) {
    // We should now launch CommunicationActivity and finish ourselves
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommunicationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return; // Don't continue the rest of onCreate()
}
// The rest of your onCreate() goes here
```

You can only use `CLEAR_TOP` to clear down to an existing activity in the activity stack. That's why your use of `CLEAR_TOP` isn't working (because `CommunicationActivity` doesn't exist in the activity stack).

This method clears all activities and launches the root activity again. When the root activity's `onCreate()` is called, it checks the Intent for the extra "foo", which it uses as a signal that it needs to launch `CommunicationActivity` and finish itself. This should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Call `activity.finish();` after you switch to other activity. This way no activity will remain on stack.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserpickActivity.this, CommunicationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);              
    startActivity(intent);

    //YOUR_ACTIVITY.finish();
```

Uncomment the above line if you want this activity to be removed from activity stack.

Comment: Please, understand. I need to finish all activities only from 4 activity, therefore I can't finish activities using "finish".

Answer (score 1):

// This will clear all activity and start new task.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserpickActivity.this, CommunicationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);              
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hello Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK clear all activity and create new task.

Comment: It doesn't actually start a new task, it just clears the existing task. And this is only available from API 11 (Android 3.0) so it doesn't work on all the devices running Android 2.x

Answer (score -1):

Use android:nohistory=true in manifest for Activities.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
```

Comment: -1 This is not a good suggestion. If the user is in Activity2 or Activity3 and presses the HOME button, he can not come back to the application. Also, the BACK button doesn't work in this scenario. `noHistory` should be used only very rarely and in special circumstances (like an Activity that is launched **only from a Notification**)